# When is a forward declaration required?

Tags: c++, forward-declaration

I have this C++ project that I'm working on.

All classes have their implementation separated from the .h file.

However, I'm not certain why/when forward declarations are required.

For example, I just ran into an error when I #included "ClassType.h", the compiler completely refused to compile a class that had a pointer to ClassType, even though class ClassType is **clearly** defined in "ClassType.h".

Why isn't it enough for the compiler to simply see that I've #included "ClassType.h", and WHY does it want a forward declaration?

```
#include "ClassType.h"

// REFUSES TO COMPILE WITHOUT forward declaration
class ClassType;

class SomeClass
{
    ClassType* instance;
};
```

Comment: Please post the content of ClassType.h

Comment: Can you post ClassType.h too?

Comment: We would need to see more about ClassType.h to provide a definitive answer.  Possibly your include guards are preventing the header from actually being included.

Comment: It wants a forward declaration because ClassType is not defined for some reason.  To know why it's not defined, we need to see ClassType.h.  If you can't provide it, try some of the answers that have been suggested and see if one of them fixes it.  Then accept an answer and let us know. 8v)

Comment: I should have said "declared", not "defined".

Answer (score 7):

Does ClassType.h include (directly or indirectly) the file you quoted, in which you're defining SomeClass?

Answer (score 3):

I'm wondering if ClassType is declared in a namespace.  Need to see ClassType.h to be sure.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you have the same header guard. Check that at the start of your header, you don't have something like this

```
#ifndef SOMECLASS_H
```

in *both* files. Those guards have to have unique names in every header file they guard from multiple inclusions. Otherwise, they will prevent inclusion of content into other headers.

Answer (score 2):

> When is a forward declaration
>   required?

It is needed when you only need to declare a pointer to a type, i.e. in a header file. The actual implementation is completely irrelevant and should **only** be needed in the .cpp files **using** any method or state of that class.

As long as a pointer is being copied, the type is irrelevant as you are merely just copying a pointer value, not the content of what the pointer points to.

```
// someclass.h
class ClassType;

class SomeClass
{
  public:
    void foo();
    ClassType* instance;
};

// someclass.cpp
void SomeClass::foo()
{
    instance->SomeMethod();  // someclass.h needed
    SomeFunction(instance);  // someclass.h irrelevant
}
```

Cheers

If this doesn't work, you probably have some problems with someclass.h

Answer (score 0):

The problem probably exists with ClassType, and not SomeClass.  Please post the listing for ClassType.h, and I believe the community will be able to help you. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a forward declaration in order to get the compile to work, then ClassType.h has something that is making your ClassType definition not make into the pre-processed source that gets compiled. Try compiling so that it leave the pre-processed file around and see what you can find there.

Answer (score 0):

In general, you need a forward declaration in any compile unit *if* the compiler hasn't seen the declaration he's trying to use. This means you need forward declarations

- if you have cyclic dependencies
- if the header doesn't properly declare the class (function, variable) you're trying to use.

Including a header file does not do any declarations -- it's just including a file, and that file could be very well empty (or made empty due to broken double inclusion protection, which can happen easily if you copy the header file from another one and forget to adjust the macro used for double inclusion protection).

In your case, I'd bet something is wrong with the `ClassType.h` file. If it does declares the class my guess is the double inclusion protection.

Answer (score 0):

in case it is a header guard of a kind

```
#ifdef SOMECLASS_H
```

then it is better to use `#pragma once` instead